# Is there a solid advantage to feeding beans to Paper Mario?

Tags: mario-and-luigi-paper-jam

So I've come across a lot of beans so far (100+) and I generally hold onto items like this until I'm in a tough position (then I'd distribute them evenly). However, it occurred to me that Paper Mario attacks with many clones. Do they inherit some of his stats? If so, is it strictly better to feed him all of the beans you find?

Comment: I can't answer your question directly but I can give you a bit of advise.  Save your game.  Distribute your beans then see what happens.  Worse case scenario, quit without saving and restore your game.